# How to separate column like 01,02,03 to rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Tabx_Test_Import
(
    ID        INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Week      NVARCHAR(2000),
    Code      NVARCHAR(20),
    Amount    NUMERIC(19, 6),
    Name      NVARCHAR(50),
    Last_Name NVARCHAR(50),
    RC        NVARCHAR(11)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE Tabx_Test_Inz
(
    ID     INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Week   INT NOT NULL,
    RC     NVARCHAR(10),
    Code   NVARCHAR(20),
    Amount NUMERIC(19, 6),
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Import (Week, Code, Amount, Name, Last_Name, RC)
VALUES (N'01,02,03', N'012016A15', 11.50, N'Juraj', N'Novotný', N'050671/8652')

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Import (Week, Code, Amount, Name, Last_Name, RC)
VALUES (N'04,05,08', N'012016G45', 22.30, N'Peter', N'Pýchly', N'030888/3553')

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Import (Week, Code, Amount, Name, Last_Name, RC)
VALUES (N'10,11,12,13', N'012016A18', 8.70, N'Juraj', N'Novotný', N'050671/8652')

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Import (Week, Code, Amount, Name, Last_Name, RC)
VALUES (N'04,05,06', N'012016T66', 12.12, N'Peter', N'Pýchly', N'030888/3553')

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Import (Week, Code, Amount, Name, Last_Name, RC)
VALUES (N'04', N'012016H11', 55.00, N'Peter', N'Pýchly', N'030888/3553')
```

Each week will be in one line - the record with weeks from the import table have to be broken for the code and the customer for so many lines
how many weeks are separated by commas.

It means one week, one customer and one code will be in one line.

```sql
INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Inz  (Week, RC, Code, Amount) 
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(Week,1,2), 
        REPLACE(RC,'/','') , Code, Amount
    FROM
        Tabx_Test_Import;

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Inz  (Week, RC, Code, Amount) 
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(Week,4,2), 
        REPLACE(RC,'/','') , Code, Amount
    FROM 
        Tabx_Test_Import;

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Inz  (Week, RC, Code, Amount) 
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(Week,7,2), 
        REPLACE(RC,'/','') , Code, Anount
    FROM 
        Tabx_Test_Import;

INSERT INTO Tabx_Test_Inz  (Week, RC, Code, Amount)
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(Week,10,2),
        REPLACE(RC,'/','') , Code, Amount
    FROM 
        Tabx_Test_Import;
```

I've tried this... But it is not correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to insert the same rows for each distinct value for *week*, you can use `string_split` for this purpose:

```
 insert into Tabx_Test_Inz (Week, RC, Code, Amount)
 select value, replace(RC,'/',''), code, amount
 from Tabx_Test_Import
 cross apply String_Split(week,',')
```

Comment: Note that you must be using SQL Server 2016+ and the database itself needs to have a compatibility level of 130 or higher (SQL Server 2016). This should not be a common problem today, but if you do get an error that no function or procedure named STRING_SPLIT exists, this is why.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. :-)

Comment: @Austin Yeah, I have some instances that remain stuck on 110 and can't use this (or 2017's STRING_AGG). Still, it really *should not* be a problem... if not for vendor laziness. It'll be another decade before I can reliably use the new ordinal column for STRING_SPLIT, too!

Comment: @BaconBits See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69928018/14868997, you can still use it if you want